# Change command for locking screen

Tags: 16.04, gnome, login, lightdm, lock-screen

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome desktop and LightDM as login manager. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or lock the screen in other ways it seems like the command `gnome-screensaver-command -l` is run. What I would rather like was if the command `dm-tool lock` was run instead, because the gnome-screensaver lock screen is pretty ugly compared to the LightDM greeter.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi tjespe, just curious, but did you manage?

Comment: Yes @JacobVlijm I managed to replace the shortcut command, but I had already done that when I read your answer. The thing is, I want to use `dm-tool lock` when the lid is closed and after suspension as well.

Comment: But that is not what you are asking. You specifically mention the shortcut, calling the command. ;/

Comment: "When I do Ctrl+Alt+L or lock the screen in other ways". Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What about the other question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/882555/suspend-on-lid-close-after-timeout

Answer (score 5):

#### Replace the shortcut command

Assuming it works the same on Gnome as it does on Unity:

1. Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "System". Click on the right side, to set a new keyboard shortcut and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. The key will show "Disabled".
2. Now move to "Custom Shortcuts" (in the left pane). Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   dm-tool lock
   ```

   and set the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Now you replaced the command, called by the shortcut.

Comment: awesome, thanks!